# Where Meteor serves it's bundle js/css from?

Tags: meteor

I have Meteor application on production server, bundled and served with node.js.

I have file like `/f8f71147843759bcc4dca8e0927d659eda1df98d.js` which is requested by client code (by default) as `/f8f71147843759bcc4dca8e0927d659eda1df98d.js?meteor_js_resource=true`.

If I request this file directly from Node application, I get it ~800kb-sized, minified/uglyfied etc.

If I set it to be served from nginx, I look for it in `bundle/programs/web.browser/f8f71147843759bcc4dca8e0927d659eda1df98d.js`

It's there, it looks minified and uglyfied but it's size is 3mb.

How to explain this?

Comment: Kinda sure there's some Gzip compression going on when served from the app.

Comment: It was definitely gzip thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kyll stated in question comment, issue was I didn't paid attention to fact that .js file was served gzipped.

Comment: So did you manage to serve the compressed version from NGinx? If so, how? It would be interesting to have that in your answer.